# Partial differential equation, Finite difference Method

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations, finite-difference-method

For my research project I am trying to solve following partial differential equation in Mathematica

```
(V[r]*ψ[u, v])/4 + Derivative[1, 1][ψ][u, v] == 0
```

with boundary conditions

```
ψ[u,v0]==0; ψ[u0,v]==Exp[-((v - vc)^2/(2 σ^2))]; vc = 10; σ = 3
```

Here (u,v) are two independent variables and `ψ` is a dependent variable. Above two-dimensional equation can be integrated numerically, using the finite difference method (suggested in some paper) as

```
Subscript[ψ, N] = Subscript[ψ, E] - Subscript[ψ, S] + Subscript[ψ, W] - 
    1/32 V δu δv (-Subscript[u, E] - Subscript[u, N] + 
    Subscript[v, N] + Subscript[v, W]) (Subscript[ψ, E] + Subscript[ψ, W])
```

Here N,W,E and S forms a rectangular grid means If you make a grid in u (y-axis) and v (x axis) then N represents (u+δu, v+δv), E represents (u, v+δv), W represents (u+δu,v) and S represents (u, v) points on the grid. δu and δv are grid spacing. One can take δu=δv=0.1 (or small). r -> { rp to Infinity}, v -> { - Infinity to 40}, u -> { - 40 to Infinity}. u0 and v0 are the starting points on the grid. You can take them anywhere provided they are consistent with above mentioned interval.

Please note that here

```
V[r]= ((-(1/(50 r^3)) + 2 r + 1/(100 r^2 rp) + rp/r^2 + rp^3/r^2) (1 + 1/(
   100 r^2) + r^2 - 1/(100 r rp) - rp/r - rp^3/r))/r
```

is a function of "r" rather than (u,v). r is related to u and v as,

```
u=t-f[r], v=t+f[r]
```

where

```
f[r]= 1/(2 KP) Log[r - rp] - 1/(2 KN) Log[r - rN] - 
 A Log[r^2 + r P + q] + (2 (B + A P))/
  Sqrt[4 q - P^2] (ArcTan[(2 r + P)/Sqrt[4 q - P^2]] - Pi/2) - 20

A = (R^2 (rp + rN) (rp^2 + rN^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))/(
  2 (3 rp^2 + rN^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2) (3 rN^2 + rp^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))

B = (R^2 (rp^2 + rN^2 + R^2) (rp^2 + rN^2 + rp rN + R^2))/((3 rp^2 + 
     rN^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2) (3 rN^2 + rp^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))

KP = ((rp - rN) (3 rp^2 + rN^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))/(2 R^2 rp^2)

KN = ((rp - rN) (3 rN^2 + rp^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))/(2 R^2 rN^2)

rN = -(rp/3) - (2^(1/3) (3 rp^2 + 2 rp^4))/(
 3 rp ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6 + Sqrt[
    4 (3 rp^2 + 2 rp^4)^3 + ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6)^2])^(
  1/3)) + ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6 + Sqrt[
   4 (3 rp^2 + 2 rp^4)^3 + ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6)^2])^(
 1/3)/(3 2^(1/3) rp)

q=rp^2 + rN^2 + rp rN + R^2

P=rp + rN

rp = 4/10

R=1.
```

So now the idea is for a particular value of u and v, `f[r]=(v-u)/2` is fixed. Then we can use f[r] equation to find r and from this r we can find V[r]. This will give V for those particular values of u and v. With this one can solve the partial differential equation and find `ψ[u,v]`.

I need a plot of `ψ[400, v]` as a function of v. The plot of `ψ[400, v]` will be oscillating and decaying. An image of the result is shown below. I would really appreciate if someone can help in this regard.

[image]

Comment: Have you actually integrate the equation numerically, as you say is possible early in your question?  Please show the calculations you actually have carried out.

Comment: @bbgodfrey...Yes, I have tried to find \[Psi][u,v] using Subscript[[Psi], N] = Subscript[[Psi], E] + Subscript[[Psi], W] - Subscript[[Psi], S] - ([Delta]u [Delta]v (Subscript[[Psi], E] + Subscript[[Psi], W]))/8 V (( Subscript[v, N] + Subscript[v, W] - Subscript[u, N] - Subscript[u, E])/4)  , but could not reproduce the results.

Comment: Boundary conditions need to be specified in order to solve the first equation numerically.  Also, your second equation has no obvious connection to the rest of your question, so it is not surprising that you could not compute `ψ` from it.

Comment: Sorry I forget to provide the boundary conditions. Here they are :                  \[Psi][u,v=v0]==0, \[Psi][u=u0,v]==Exp[-((v - vc)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))]. you can take vc==10 and \[Sigma]=3

Comment: @bbgodfrey..."your second equation has no obvious connection to the rest of your question, so it is not surprising that you could not compute ψ from it". I could not understand this. I am using second equation  to find \[Psi][u,v]. If you make a grid in u (y-axis) and v (x axis) then N represents (u+δu, v+δv), E represents (u, v+δv), W represents (u+δu,v) and S represents (u, v) points on the grid.

Comment: The equations contain numerous undefined quantities.

Comment: @bbgodfrey.. .sorry for that. Now I have provided all the details. Please check it again. If you find any other problem please let me know.

Comment: `R` remains undefined, and the question now contains two inconsistent definitions for `rN`.  Yu do not make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @bbgodfrey....R=1. Both definitions of rN were same. I have removed one of them. Sorry for all the inconvenience.

Comment: @belisarius has setted..I have modified my question. Please see it. I need a plot of ψ[u=400, v] as a function of v. Here u=400 (a choice) just represents a grid size.  If you find any other problem please let me know. I will try to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: @Lou... I have modified my question. Please see it. I need a plot of ψ[u=400, v] as a function of v. Here u=400 (a choice) just represents a grid size.  If you find any other problem please let me know. I will try to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: @blochwave.. I have modified my question. Please see it. I need a plot of ψ[u=400, v] as a function of v. Here u=400 (a choice) just represents a grid size.  If you find any other problem please let me know. I will try to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: @m_goldberg... I have modified my question. Please see it. I need a plot of ψ[u=400, v] as a function of v. Here u=400 (a choice) just represents a grid size.  If you find any other problem please let me know. I will try to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: @xzczd.. I have modified my question. Please see it. I need a plot of ψ[u=400, v] as a function of v. Here u=400 (a choice) just represents a grid size.  If you find any other problem please let me know. I will try to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: @bbgodfrey...I have slightly modified the definition of f[r].

Comment: 1. What's the value of `u0` and `v0`? 2. What's the range of `u`, `v`, `r`? 3. Is finite difference method necessary? Can `NDSolve` be used?

Comment: @xzczd... r->{ rp to Infinity}, v->{ - Infinity to 40}, u->{ - 40 to Infinity}. u0 and v0 are the starting points on the grid. You can take them anywhere provided they are consistent with above mentioned interval. Actually the paper I am trying to reproduce is using finite difference method as stated in eq. 3. It would have been better if i put an image of the output here. But I dont know how to put an Image here.

Comment: You should include all this in your question.

Comment: I managed to solve the equation, as soon as this question is reopened, I'll post an answer. But with my arbitrarily chosen `u0` and `v0`, the image I obtained is quite different from yours.

Comment: @xzczd...Can you please post the code. If you getting oscillating and decaying behavior of \[Psi] then your are probably right. The  \[Psi] on the y-axis is in log scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, I didn't reproduce the image you gave, maybe my arbitrarily chosen `u0` and `v0` are not proper, maybe I've made a mistake somewhere, maybe something is wrong with the equation you provided. Anyway I'll show my 2 solutions below, one with `NDSolve`, the other with FDM using the difference scheme you provided, the results of the 2 solutions are consistent.

First of all, define all the provided formulas into rules and functions:

```
Clear["`*"]
rule = ReleaseHold[
   Hold[{f[r] = 
       Log[r - rp]/(2 KP) - Log[r - rN]/(2 KN) - 
        A Log[r^2 + r P + q] + ((2 (B + A P)) (ArcTan[(2 r + P)/Sqrt[4 q - P^2]] - π/
           2))/Sqrt[4 q - P^2] - 20, 
      A = (R^2 (rp + rN) (rp^2 + rN^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))/(
       2 (3 rp^2 + rN^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2) (3 rN^2 + rp^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2)), 
      B = (R^2 (rp^2 + rN^2 + R^2) (rp^2 + rN^2 + rp rN + R^2))/((3 rp^2 + rN^2 + 
          2 rp rN + R^2) (3 rN^2 + rp^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2)), 
      KP = ((rp - rN) (3 rp^2 + rN^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))/(2 R^2 rp^2), 
      KN = ((rp - rN) (3 rN^2 + rp^2 + 2 rp rN + R^2))/(2 R^2 rN^2), 
      rN = -(rp/3) - (2^(1/3) (3 rp^2 + 2 rp^4))/(
        3 rp ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6 + Sqrt[
           4 (3 rp^2 + 2 rp^4)^3 + ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6)^2])^(
         1/3)) + ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6 + Sqrt[
          4 (3 rp^2 + 2 rp^4)^3 + ((27 rp^2)/100 + 9 rp^4 + 7 rp^6)^2])^(1/3)/(
        3 2^(1/3) rp), q = rp^2 + rN^2 + rp rN + R^2, P = rp + rN, rp = 4/10, R = 1}] /. 
    Set -> Rule];

f[r_] = Block[{f}, f[r] //. rule];

V[r_] = ((-(1/(50 r^3)) + 2 r + 1/(100 r^2 rp) + rp/r^2 + rp^3/r^2) (1 + 1/(100 r^2) + 
      r^2 - 1/(100 r rp) - rp/r - rp^3/r))/r /. rule;
```

Before moving on, it's worth analyzing the property of $f(r)$ and $v(r)$ first:

```
f[r] // N // Simplify
Limit[f[r], r -> 4/10]
Limit[f[r], r->Infinity]
Plot[f[x], {x, 4/10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
(* -Infinity *)
(* -20 *)
(* -21.2263 + 0.780691 ArcTan[0.198677 + 0.942968 r] + 0.282187 Log[-0.4 + r] - 
   0.001025 Log[-0.0213856 + r] - 0.140581 Log[1.16901 + 0.421386 r + r^2] *)
```

[image]

It's not hard to notice $f(r)$ is a function defined in $(\frac{4}{10}, \infty)$ , monotone increasing from $-\infty$ to $-20$.

```
V[r] // N // Simplify
Plot[V[r], {r, -30, 20}]
(* (2. (0.01 - 0.489 r + 1. r^2 + r^4) (-0.01 + 0.2445 r + 1. r^4))/r^6 *)
```

[image]

$V(r)$ changes quickly near $0$.

Let's go on solving the PDE. Your equation is a first order PDE with a extreme variable coefficient, to solve it, one of the troublesome parts is determining $r$.

Since $f(r)$ is monotone and $f(r)=\frac{v-u}{2}$, we have $r=f^{(-1)}(\frac{v-u}{2})$. To calculate the inverse function of `f`, a direct use of `InverseFunction` is inefficient, so I choose interpolation for this task:

```
interinversef = 
 Interpolation[Transpose@{f@#, #} &@N[Range[4/10 + 10^-10, 100 + 10^-10, 1/100], 256]]
```

*I've chosen a (probably unnecessary) high precision here to make sure the later calculation won't suffer from precision issue.*

This is not the end, notice that I've only inversed the function from `4/10 + 10^-10` to `100 + 10^-10`, because the variation of the function value near `4/10` is extremely fast and that after `100` is extremely slow and extents to infinity so interpolation is again insufficient. Here I choose 2 analytic approximation

```
frestpart1[r_] = f[r] /. Log[-(2/5) + r] -> 0;
fappro1[r_] = f[r] - frestpart1[r] + frestpart1[4/10];
inversefappro1[uv_] = InverseFunction[fappro1][uv] // First;

fappro2[r_] = f[r] /. Log[_] -> 0;
inversefappro2[uv_] = InverseFunction[fappro2][uv][[1]];
```

*The selection of `fappro2` isn't quite accurate actually, but I think it's enough <strike>and can't think out a better one currently</strike>.*

Then we combine all these into one function:

```
With[{lowerbound = f[4/10 + 10^-10], upperbound = f[100 + 10^-10]}, 
  inversef[uv_] := 
   Piecewise[{{inversefappro2[uv], -20 > uv > upperbound}, {inversefappro1@uv, 
      uv < lowerbound}, {interinversef@uv, lowerbound <= uv <= upperbound}}]];
```

And solve the equation with `NDSolve`:

```
{u0 = 370, v0 = -10, uend = 400, vend = 20};
AbsoluteTiming[
 sol = NDSolveValue[{(1/4) V[r] ψ[u, v] + Derivative[1, 1][ψ][u, v] == 
      0, ψ[u, v0] == 0, ψ[u0, v] == Exp[-((v - vc)^2/(2 σ^2))]} /. 
         {vc -> 10, σ -> 3, r -> inversef[(v - u)/2]}, ψ, {u, u0, uend}, {v, 
    v0, vend}]]
Plot3D[sol[u, v], {u, u0, uend}, {v, v0, vend}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Hmm… no oscillation. Let's double-check it with FDM:

```
Clear@p
ugrid = 100; vgrid = 100; du = N[(uend - u0)/ugrid, 256]; dv = N[(vend - v0)/vgrid, 256];

formula = Subscript[ψ, E] - Subscript[ψ, S] + Subscript[ψ, W] - 
          1/32 V δu δv (-Subscript[u, E] - Subscript[u, N] + Subscript[v, 
             N] + Subscript[v, W]) (Subscript[ψ, E] + Subscript[ψ, W]);

vboundary[v_] = Exp[-((v - vc)^2/(2 σ^2))] /. {vc -> 10, σ -> N[3, 256]};

(p[{#, 0}] = N[0, 256]) & /@ Range[0, ugrid];
(p[{0, #}] = vboundary[v0 + # dv]) & /@ Range[0, vgrid];

With[{expr = 
   Function[{m, n}, #] &[
    formula /. 
      Subscript[a_, b_] :> a[b] /. 
      {N -> {m + 1, n + 1}, S -> {m, n}, E -> {m, n + 1}, W -> {m + 1, n}} /. 
      {ψ -> p, δu -> du, δv -> dv, u -> First, v -> Last} /. 
      V -> V[inversef[(v0 + n dv - (u0 + m du))/2]] /. 
      {m -> m - 1, n -> n - 1}]}, 
    p[{m_, n_}] := p[{m, n}] = expr[m, n]]

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500, $RecursionLimit = ∞}, p[{ugrid, vgrid}]];// AbsoluteTiming
dat = Table[p[{m, n}], {m, 0, ugrid}, {n, 0, vgrid}];

ListPlot3D[dat, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Looks the same as the result from `NDSolve`.

## Epilog

I tend to guess my `u0` and `v0` isn't proper, currently value of `(v-u)/2` is far from `-20`, while `inversef` varies quickly near `-20`.

To verify this guess, a smaller grid size is needed. The δu=δv=0.1 suggested by you is probably not enough given

```
inversef[-20.3] // N
inversef[-20.03] // N
inversef[-20.003] // N

(* 3.24399 *)
(* 33.3234 *)
(* 275.757 *)
```

I think the verification won't be too hard and I'll leave it to you. Now I'd like to stop here and go to bed.

Comment: @xzczd...Thank you very much for your help..

Comment: @mat You are welcome. If you feel satisfied with the answer, you can click the [click the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/) in the left-top corner of the answer to accept it.